# (Beginner peroblem) Check if one list belongs to a list made out of lists

Tags: haskell

So I want to check if a list belongs to the permutations of [1..6]. My idea was this:

```
>import Data.List

>perm = permutations [1..6]

>funk3 :: [Int] -> Bool
>funk3 [] = False
>funk3 (x:xs) = if (x:xs) == perm
>           then True
>           else False
```

I know that the following code in incorrect, because I can't compare a list with a list, which contains more lists. But I really don't know how to tell Haskell that my list is only a partial quantity. Pleas help me!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `elem` to check for membership.

```
funk3 :: [Int] -> Bool
funk3 xs = elem xs perm
```

This is rather inefficient, though, since there is no need to generate all the 720 permutations. We can sort the input list and simply compare it to [1..6].

```
funk3 :: [Int] -> Bool
funk3 xs = sort xs == [1..6]
```

Or, if we want to avoid sorting a potentially large list,

```
funk3 :: [Int] -> Bool
funk3 xs@[_,_,_,_,_,_] = sort xs == [1..6]
funk3 _                = False
```

Comment: @epsilonhalbe It does not scale, though. I guess `null (drop 1000 xs) && sort xs == [1..1000]` could be used. We need an idiomatic way to check `length xs == 1000` without scanning all of `xs`. Using `genericLength` and Peano naturals could be it? Dropping both `n-1` (not null required) and dropping one more (null required)?